# Regex with Letters, Numbers, @ and spaces

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

I would like to know how to write a regex in c# that allows only
numbers, letters, spaces and the `@` symbol.

Valid inputs are:

- `Abc`
- `Abc def`
- `@Abc`
- `Abc@`

Example I tried so far: `@"[^\w-\s-@]"`

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far? How about some sample strings to show what you're looking to match?

Comment: @"[^\w-\s-@]" so far
example: Marisa
: Marisa Test
: @Marisa

Comment: And what about that doesn't work? Please add to your question, not comments.

Comment: If you only need ASCII letters, use `@"^[A-Za-z0-9\s@]*$"` or `@"^[A-Za-z0-9\s@]*\z"`. For Unicode ones, use `@"^[\p{L}\p{N}\s@]*$"`.

Comment: @BlueBockser We do not know if an empty string should be allowed or not. The question is rather unclear.

Comment: @BlueBockser [It will never match `!"§$`](https://regex101.com/r/cWs4Y3/1) due to the anchors.

Comment: Yoan, did any of the suggestions above work? Please let know so that the question could be answered.

Comment: I tried something else, which worked, maybe it can be simplified down..to..
`@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\s@ ]*$"`

Comment: That is exactly my pattern, but you do not need the space since `\s` already matches all whitespace. I will post for you to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
@"^[A-Za-z0-9\s@]*$"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sFsNRn/1)

The pattern matches:

- `^` - start of the string
- `[A-Za-z0-9\s@]*` - zero or more (`*`, if you do not want to match an empty string, use `+`, 1 or more) occurrences of ASCII letters, digits, any whitespace and `@` chars
- `$` - end of string (replace with `\z` if you do not want to match if the matching string ends with `\n` char).

Comment: Thanks for the help